# Resposive A Img CSS

Tags: image, css

Trying to add a background image in css on an a tag and make it responsive within a div!
Everytime the I resize the browser the image stays the same size. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Have set up a  **[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/08zd25qb/)**

Here is my code....

**HTML**

```
<div id="logo" class="col-md-8">
<a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" title="WINNING POST BREWERY & PUB">WINNING POST BREWERY & PUB</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#logo {
    text-align:center;
    height:auto;
    min-height:145px;
    background:rgb(212,228,239);
    background:rgba(212,228,239,.2);
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(212,228,239,.2)0%,rgba(134,174,204,.8)100%);
    background:-webkit-gradient(left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,rgba(212,228,239,.2)),color-stop(100%,rgba(134,174,204,.8)));
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(212,228,239,.2)0%,rgba(134,174,204,.8)100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,rgba(212,228,239,.2)0%,rgba(134,174,204,.8)100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top,rgba(212,228,239,.2)0%,rgba(134,174,204,.8)100%);
    background:linear-gradient(top,rgba(212,228,239,.2)0%,rgba(134,174,204,.8)100%);
    -webkit-border-radius:8px;
    -moz-border-radius:8px;
    -ms-border-radius:8px;
    -o-border-radius:8px;
    border-radius:8px;
    border:1px solid #0D4364;
    box-shadow:0 1px 1px #79C6FF;
    padding:6px;
}
#logo a{
    background-image:url('ASSETS/logo.png');
    background-position:0 0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    background-size:cover
}
```

Comment: See my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: can you explain why your `#logo` rule has following two properties `height:auto; min-height:145px;` ? Looks like you think the height of `#logo` can go above `145px` somehow? if yes then what is going to cause this increase in height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting 
 `` background-size:100% 100%` instead of `cover` ``

```css
#logo {
 text-align:center;
 height:auto;
 min-height:145px;
    width:80%;
 background:rgb(212,228,239);
 background:rgba(212,228,239,.2);
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(212,228,239,.2)0%,rgba(134,174,204,.8)100%);
 background:-webkit-gradient(left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,rgba(212,228,239,.2)),color-stop(100%,rgba(134,174,204,.8)));
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(212,228,239,.2)0%,rgba(134,174,204,.8)100%);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,rgba(212,228,239,.2)0%,rgba(134,174,204,.8)100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top,rgba(212,228,239,.2)0%,rgba(134,174,204,.8)100%);
 background:linear-gradient(top,rgba(212,228,239,.2)0%,rgba(134,174,204,.8)100%);
 -webkit-border-radius:8px;
 -moz-border-radius:8px;
 -ms-border-radius:8px;
 -o-border-radius:8px;
 border-radius:8px;
 border:1px solid #0D4364;
 box-shadow:0 1px 1px #79C6FF;
 padding:6px;
    height:2vw;
}
#logo a{
 background-image:url('http://www.winningpostworcester.co.uk/wp-content/themes/WinningPost/ASSETS/logo.png');
 background-position:0 0;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 margin:0 auto;
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 text-indent:-9999px;
 background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo" class="col-md-8">
    <a href="#" title="WINNING POST BREWEry">WINNING POST BREWERY & PUB</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your requirements if you want to set the width of the logo to 100%; then you should use `background-size:contain;` and `background-position:center center;`.

This way the banner will keep its aspect ration contained inside the parent div.

You can change the value of min-height according to your needs. Remember to apply it to both, link and container.

```css
#logo {
 text-align:center;
    width:100%;
 min-height:145px;
 background:rgb(212,228,239);
 background:rgba(212,228,239,.2);
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(212,228,239,.2)0%,rgba(134,174,204,.8)100%);
 background:-webkit-gradient(left top,left bottom,color-stop(0%,rgba(212,228,239,.2)),color-stop(100%,rgba(134,174,204,.8)));
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(212,228,239,.2)0%,rgba(134,174,204,.8)100%);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(top,rgba(212,228,239,.2)0%,rgba(134,174,204,.8)100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top,rgba(212,228,239,.2)0%,rgba(134,174,204,.8)100%);
 background:linear-gradient(top,rgba(212,228,239,.2)0%,rgba(134,174,204,.8)100%);
 -webkit-border-radius:8px;
 -moz-border-radius:8px;
 -ms-border-radius:8px;
 -o-border-radius:8px;
 border-radius:8px;
 border:1px solid #0D4364;
 box-shadow:0 1px 1px #79C6FF;
 padding:6px;
}
#logo a{
 background-image:url('http://www.winningpostworcester.co.uk/wp-content/themes/WinningPost/ASSETS/logo.png');
 background-position:center center;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
    min-height:145px;
 margin:0 auto;
 display:inline-block;
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 text-indent:-9999px;
 background-size:contain;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo" class="col-md-8">
    <a href="#" title="WINNING POST BREWEry">WINNING POST BREWERY & PUB</a>
</div>
```